# A confusion in understanding a solution to a number theory problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, chinese-remainder-theorem

> Prove that there exists a positive integer n, such that for all
> integers $k$ the number $k^2+k+n$ has no prime divisors less than
> $2008$.

Here is the solution my book gave
[image]

I don't understand why such $r$ exists? Could anyone explain to help me understand? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please [do not use images to convey critical information not otherwise present in your post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Comment: The map that sends $k$, $0\leq k\leq p-1$ to the remainder of $k^2+k$ modulo $p$ is not injective, so it is not surjective either.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Could u explain why the map not being injective implies not being surjective?

Comment: Maps from a finite set to itself are injective if and only if the are surjective if and only if they are bijective. Perhaps think about it a bit?

Answer (score 8):

The example stated means that as already $2$ values of $k$( $k \equiv 0 \mod{p}$ and $k \equiv p-1 \mod{p}$) give the same remainder($k^2+k \equiv 0 \mod{p}$), then there are $p-2$(congruent to $\pmod{p}$) more values of $k$ which have to attain $p-1$ remainders.
This can not happen and atleast a remainder will exist which is never attained by $k^2+k$.